# Why do JUnit DataPoints methods not work for primitives?

Tags: java, junit

When running the following MWE, the test `testDataPointsMethodFailsForPrimitives` fails with an `AssertionError: Never found parameters that satisfied method assumptions.  Violated assumptions: []` but passes fine when uncommenting the data points created as static members of the test class. `testDataPointsMethodWorksForObjects`, on the other hand, works just dandy as is.

Why is it that data points that are primitives are not recognised by JUnit when created through a method but data points that are objects are?

```
import org.junit.experimental.theories.DataPoints;
import org.junit.experimental.theories.Theories;
import org.junit.experimental.theories.Theory;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Theories.class)
public class MWE {

//    @DataPoints
//    public static int[] primitiveArray = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

    @DataPoints
    public static int[] primitiveMethod() {
        return new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    }

    @DataPoints
    public static Integer[] objectMethod() {
        return new Integer[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    }

    @Theory
    public void testDataPointsMethodFailsForPrimitives(int primitive) {
    }

    @Theory
    public void testDataPointsMethodWorksForObjects(Integer primitive) {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is fixed in the 4.12 beta versions of JUnit. Here's a description of the issue, and its resolution: https://github.com/junit-team/junit/issues/637

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem is caused by a bug in junit-4.11. This is particularly problematic if you are using Intellij since it comes by default with junit-4.11.

Here is how I fixed it:

1. Click on the "Project Structure" icon in your tool bar, or Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S to bring up the project settings.
2. Click "Libraries" then "+" then "From Maven..."
3. Search Junit and select junit:junit:4.12-beta-3 and follow the instructions to save the jar file into your project's lib/ directory.
4. Go back to your main editor windows' project panel, expand the "External Libraries" entry in the panel. If there is a junit-4.11 in the dependencies, this is the one that comes with Intellij. Just delete it and rebuild your code.

After that you are able to use `@DataPoints` with primitive data type, such as:

```
    @DataPoints
    public static int[] primitiveMethod() {
       System.out.println("creating data points ...");
       return new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    }

    @Theory
    public void testDataPointsMethodFailsForPrimitives(int primitive) {
    }
```